# Frigidaire gas range - first use. Is it packing material?

Tags: gas, stove

Just got a Frigidaire gas range and the neighbor said when she used hers (same one) fire started because the packing material wasn't removed from the inside of the stove.

I opened stove's door, unscrewed two screws from the back and removedvthe bottom cover. The only thing I see is this insulation material. Is it insulation? Packaging material? Does it need to be removed?
[image]

Comment: Doesn't the owner's manual contain instructions on first startup? I would be very surprised if you had to unscrew things and remove panels.

Comment: It has no instructions regarding it. It only says remove packing material. And the neighbor who moved a week before us, and has a brand new gas range as well, said it went up on fire because of packing material. Anyhow, if you're not helping, please don't state the obvious.

Comment: Sorry, but you took my comment the wrong way. It is not a given that you consulted the owner's manual, as you did not mention that in the question.

Comment: Cool. Sorry to be snappy

Comment: Can you be more specific about what in the photo you want to remove?

Answer (score 4):

You need to read through your owners manual. Set up procedures should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Also, don't take everything you hear at face value. Not being rude towards your neighbor, but they could have left an obvious piece of packaging within the range. As long as you do what you know is right by the installation, it'll all be alright. If it doesn't, it's probably not the packaging and should be returned or make use of the warranty.